# missing resource when using rosdep install

Tags: linux, dependencies, ros, drone.io

Today when I tried to follow the instructions on this [website](https://github.com/Vision4UAV/cvg_ardrone2_ibvs). I was following all the instructions, including downloading ROS library on my system, which is Ubuntu 14.10, installing packages and setting the environment. However, I stopped at

```
$ cd ${IBVS_STACK}
$ source setup.sh
$ rospack profile
$ rosdep update
$ cd ${IBVS_WORKSPACE}/src/extStack
$ rosdep install ardrone_autonomy
```

when I tried to run

```
 $ rosdep install ardrone_autonomy
```

It shows

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query 
Missing resource ardrone_autonomy
```

while ardrone_autonomy just locate right in my directory ~/src/extStack. I tried to use `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/src/extStack/ardrone_autonomy` but it still doesn't work. Can anyone possibly tell me what happened to this and what should I do with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's just a suggestion, I would prefer to comment but I can't.

Have you tried to install directly the missing package?
`apt-get install ros-*-ardrone-autonomy`, where you have to replace '*' with your ROS version (e.g. `apt-get install ros-indigo-ardrone-autonomy`)

Comment: Helped me out on a similar problem with the 'joy' package.

Answer (score 0):

From http://answers.ros.org/question/75241/install-ros-dependencies-from-apt/?answer=75262#post-id-75262 (slightly modified):

```
If you have a catkin CATKIN_WORKSPACE with some sources checked out and you want all the rosdep dependencies installed use the following

    rosdep install --from-paths CATKIN_WORKSPACE --ignore-src --rosdistro=ROSDISTRO
```

That said, I suggest in your case:

```
cd %CATKIN_WORKSPACE%
rosdep install --from-paths WORKSPACE --ignore-src --rosdistro=ROSDISTRO
```

---

Besides, ROS has its own very active forum http://answers.ros.org/.